# Creation of UI from worker tread in macos/ios

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, multiprocess, multi-window

I tried to built the UI and update it from the worker thread in macos, which threw an 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' stating the reason as 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'.

I got to know the reason that we cannot drive UI from any other thread apart from 'main' thread, which is fine. But i do have few queries regarding this, which i could'nt able to find by reading the docs.

How do we manage multiple windows in a single main thread?
I mean to say, , if multiple processes are running for my application– each with their own window – we have multiple main threads, i.e for each window, one main thread, that sounds great.

Now, when we have ONE process running, but with multiple windows – How do we mange that and what are the expectations?

Any thought or a good document on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact issue with managing multiple windows in the same main thread, which you’re trying to address?

Comment: wanted to know the lifecycle of all the  windows created from the main window on the main thread